# DNS broken when using ifupdown and systemd-resolved after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, systemd-resolved, ifupdown

TL;DR

```
sudo cp -p /etc/network/if-up.d/resolved /etc/network/if-up.d/.resolved.broken-orig

#Edit /etc/network/if-up.d/resolved and take out the extraneous quotes on lines 48 and 52
#The fix looks like:
diff /etc/network/if-up.d/.resolved.broken-orig /etc/network/if-up.d/resolved
48c48
< "$DNS"="$NEW_DNS"
---
> $DNS="$NEW_DNS"
52c52
< "$DOMAINS"="$NEW_DOMAINS"
---
> $DOMAINS="$NEW_DOMAINS"
```

At least, this appears to be effective.

---

Recently upgraded an older system to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS via `do-release-upgrade` and ran into DNS issues, error messages were:

```
nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

and

```
/etc/network/if-down.d/resolved: 12: mystatedir: not found
/etc/network/if-up.d/resolved: 71: DNS: not found
/etc/network/if-up.d/resolved: 1: /run/network/ifupdown-inet-em1: DNS=8.8.8.8: not found
/etc/network/if-up.d/resolved: 2: /run/network/ifupdown-inet-em1: DOMAINS=local_search_domain.com: not found
Failed to parse DNS server address: DNS
Failed to set DNS configuration: Invalid argument
```

when attempting to run an `nslookup` via a network connection (em1) defined in /etc/network/interfaces prior to the system upgrade.

After a period of self-soothing I located https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1981103 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1910273 which helped enhance my calm. It appears that, at a minimum, the errors encountered were due to a pair of typos in /etc/network/if-up.d/resolved which are easily fixed with a text editor; after manually removing the extraneous quotes I am able to bring up the network interface and query DNS servers. It's unclear to me if there are other issues with the `ifupdown` package currently shipped by Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (0.8.36+nmu1ubuntu3) or the manual edit I described above. Are there any documented fixes that don't involve editing lines 48 and 52 of /etc/network/if-up.d/resolved or is this the best workaround currently available for legacy systems that have been upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What happens and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I bumped my Ubuntu server `18.04->22.04` and ran into this issue. As you clearly stated (thank you!) updating `/etc/network/if-up.d/resolved` and removing 2 quoted variables in such a way:

```
sudo vim /etc/network/if-up.d/.resolved.broken-orig

Old: "$DNS"="$NEW_DNS"
-->
New: $DNS="$NEW_DNS"

Old: "$DOMAINS"="$NEW_DOMAINS"
-->
New: $DOMAINS="$NEW_DOMAINS"
```

Solves this problem after a reboot.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Note that the link posted by OP has the complete set of fixes required. It is not just these two lines (at least in my case). Also, `if-down.d` also requires fixes.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for this - I had a similar problem on Linux Mint 21.2 today, and had to change the `/etc/network/if-up.d/resolved` file so that the lines read:
`DNS="$NEW_DNS"` and `DOMAINS="$NEW_DOMAINS"`
i.e. without the $ and quotes on the left hand side.